Mouse sensitivity on Minecraft too slow
Since I downloaded shaders and put them into my Lunar client Minecraft, my Minecraft mouse sensitivity has been extremely slow. For context, my mouse has a DPI button but I disabled it and it doesn't affect my normal mouse outside of Minecraft or inside of Minecraft, I do not have cinematic mode on because I know what it is and the sensitivity doesn't change while active or inactive, and finally, after my issue with my sensitivity in Lunar client, when I went back to the normal vanilla Minecraft launcher, the slow sensitivity stayed the same.
I have absolutely no clue why my Minecraft sensitivity is so slow. It's so slow in fact that even on hyperspeed, the sensitivity is still slower than be normal sensitivity. It's as if My minecraft sensitivity is always multiplied by a number less than one. My mouse sensitivity in the menu is the exact same as my normal desktop mouse sensitivity but only when I am controlling the crosshair, is when the sensitivity dips significantly.
The last complaint is that when I go back to other versions of Minecraft, my sensitivity is broken in a different way being delayed a lot more than normal and a lot faster than normal even on yawn.
Someone please tell what happened and how I can fix it. I hope this is enough information.
